# Resample (increase the pixel size) a satellite image using a Gaussian filter in Python

Tags: python, raster, gaussian, gaussianblur, landsat

I have a satellite image (Landsat 8, panchromatic band) at 15m pixel size. My goal is to upscale the image (i.e., change the pixel size) at 460m using a `Gaussian filter` with sigma = 0.5. Is there a function in `python` that can do this (i.e., increase the pixel size using a `Gaussian filter`)? I don't have an example to show as I couldn't find how can I do this in `python`. [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18_1Kshb8WbT04gwOw4d_xhfQenULDXdB?usp=sharing) is the image.

Comment: ans what did you find in internet? First result from Google for `gaussian filter python` : [scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html)

Comment: I think this function's output is tan array with the same dimensions as the input. Am I right? My goal is to upscale an image using a gaussian filter and not nearest neighbor or bilinear

Comment: This means that I don't want to apply the `gaussian filter` and then upscale the image using for example `bilinear interpolation`. I want the upscaling method to be the `gaussian filter`. If I am not mistaken, `ArcGIS Pro (v3.0)` has a resampling technique called `Gauss blur`, but it doesn't allow me to set the `std`.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Pyresample](https://pyresample.readthedocs.io/en/latest/swath.html) it has `resample_gauss`

This function allows you to specify `sigma`, `radius_of_influence` and other parameters.

In your case as you want to decrease the resolution of the input image, you just need to define the output height and width based on the target resolution and the area extent.

Please check the above link for details.

Answer (score 0):

Pyresample is best to do it, but it works with WGS only. Here is my implementation with pyresample, gdal and pyproj:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import pyresample as pr
import numpy as np
from pyresample.geometry import AreaDefinition
import pyproj


# Get the initial details
file_in = "your_file.tif"
file_out = "output_file.tif"
new_res = 460.0
epsg = 7767 #EPSG of your tiff
radius_of_influence = new_res
pixel = 1
sigmas = new_res * pixel

# Open the raster
ds = gdal.Open(file_in, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
rb_ = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
img_arr = rb_.ReadAsArray()
gt_ = ds.GetGeoTransform()

# Get raster dimension
x_min = gt_[0]
x_size = gt_[1]
y_min = gt_[3]
y_size = gt_[5]
x_max = x_min + np.shape(img_arr)[1] * x_size
y_max = y_min + np.shape(img_arr)[0] * y_size
area_extent_old = (x_min, y_max, x_max, y_min)

# Compute new dimensions
new_width = int((x_max - x_min) / new_res)
new_height = int((y_max - y_min) / new_res)
x_max_new = x_min + (new_width * new_res)
y_max_new = y_min + (new_height * new_res)
area_extent = (x_min, y_max_new, x_max_new, y_min)

# Compute the latitudes and longitudes mesh for Swath definition (only 4326 EPSG available)
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, np.shape(img_arr)[1])
y = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, np.shape(img_arr)[0])
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)
lats, lons = np.copy(xv), np.copy(yv)

to_proxy_transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(f"epsg:{epsg}", 'epsg:4326')
for i in range(np.shape(img_arr)[1]):
    for j in range(np.shape(img_arr)[0]):
        lats[j, i], lons[j, i] = to_proxy_transformer.transform(xv[j, i], yv[j, i])

# Define Area definition and Swath definition for pyresample
projection = f"+init=EPSG:{epsg}"
area_id = 'my_area'
description = 'somewhere'
proj_id = 'my_area'

swath_def = pr.geometry.SwathDefinition(lons=lons, lats=lats)
area_def = AreaDefinition(area_id, description, proj_id, projection, new_width, -new_height, area_extent)

# Perform the resampling
values = pr.kd_tree.resample_gauss(source_geo_def=swath_def, data=img_arr, target_geo_def=area_def, radius_of_influence=radius_of_influence, sigmas=sigmas, fill_value=False)

# Define new tif parameters
img_params_ = {}
img_params_["cols"] = values.shape[1]
img_params_["rows"] = values.shape[0]
img_params_["px_width"] = (area_def.area_extent[2] - area_def.area_extent[0]) / img_params_["cols"]
img_params_["px_height"] = (area_def.area_extent[1] - area_def.area_extent[3]) / img_params_["rows"]
img_params_["origin_x"] = area_def.area_extent[0]
img_params_["origin_y"] = area_def.area_extent[3]

# Write the geotiff file
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
out_raster = driver.Create(file_out, img_params_["cols"], img_params_["rows"], 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
out_raster.SetGeoTransform((img_params_["origin_x"], img_params_["px_width"], 0, img_params_["origin_y"], 0, img_params_["px_height"]))
out_band = out_raster.GetRasterBand(1)
out_band.SetNoDataValue(0.0)
out_band.WriteArray(np.array(values))
out_raster_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
out_raster_srs.ImportFromEPSG(epsg)
out_raster.SetProjection(out_raster_srs.ExportToWkt())

# Flush the memory
out_band.FlushCache()
out_band.ComputeStatistics(False)
out_band = None
out_raster = None
```